# Chat simultaneously thinks I'm logged in and logged out

Tags: bug, chat, login, openid

I am demonstrably logged in to chat, because I'm able to talk in any room. Within a room, I also have access to moderator functionality. All that is normal and expected.

Likewise, when visiting the chat home page, [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com), I appear logged in, with my user card appearing in the top bar.

However, when visiting other pages on chat, I'm shown as logged out. My user card does not show up in the top bar, but instead a link to log in. Neither do I have access to moderator tooling, such as tools on user profiles, or the list of recent flags.

After some digging, I have come up with a solution and a possible cause: cookies. When I am **correctly** logged in, I get the following cookies from `chat.stackexchange.com`:

- `sechatusr`
- `x`

When I am **incorrectly** shown as logged out, I have the following:

- `.ASPXBrowserOverride`
- `_ga`
- `__qca`
- `sechatusr`
- `sechatusr` (not a typo, I have two of these)
- `acct`
- `prov`
- `x`

I suspect `acct` and `prov` have something to do with the SE OpenID login I use; `_ga` is a Google Analytics cookie; `.ASPXBrowserOverride` is from ASP.NET, and `__qca` is the Quantcast analytics cookie. Deleting all of these, along with one of the double `sechatusr` cookies, resolves the problem: I'm logged in everywhere.

What gives, and what do I need to do/not do?

Comment: Similar things happened for me sometimes.

Comment: Can you print out the domain and path for your dublicated cookie, this could give some clues for the SE team where it's coming from